# Dapper - creating objects with queries on database with one-to-many and many-to-many relationships

Tags: c#, .net, database, sqlite, dapper

I have an Sqlite database, for a which a partial schema is:
[image]

In the code, classes representing the data are as follows (simplified):

```
public Book : Item
{
    public ICollection<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Author> Authors { get; set; }
    public Publisher publisher { get; set; }
    // other properties...
}

public class Publisher
{
    public ICollection<Book> Books { get; set; }
    // other properties...
}

public class Author
{
    public ICollection<Author> Authors { get; set; }
}

public class Tag
{
    public ICollection<Item> Items { get; set; }
}
```

I need to return an `IEnumerable<Book>`, with the `Book` objects containing all `Author`, `Publisher` and `Tag` data for each `Book`. Currently, I have the following code, which solves the problem of getting publisher data:

```
public IEnumerable<Book> GetAllBooks()
{
    using (var db = new SqliteConnection(connectionString)
    {
        var sql = "SELECT * FROM Books as B " +
                  "INNER JOIN Publishers AS P On B.publisherId = P.id;";
        var allBooks = db.Query<Book, Publisher, Book>(sql, (book, publisher) =>
        {
             book.publisher = publisher;
             return book;
        });
        return allBooks;
    }
}
```

How to get the remaining data for a `Book` (ie `Author` and `Tag` data with the many-to-many relationships as seen in the schema) ?

Comment: Do you mean retrieve the collections of `Author`(s) and `Tag`(s) for each `Book` inside `GetAllBooks()`?

Comment: @LuckyBrain that's correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It wouldn't be very efficient if you go querying book by book so my recommendation is to query first all `Author`(s) including their `Book.id` then query all `Tag`(s) including their `Book.id` and then use `LINQ` to match by `Book.id` over the results of those queries as follows:

```js
public IEnumerable<Book> GetAllBooks()
{
    using (var db = new SqliteConnection(connectionString))
    {
        var authorsSql = "SELECT A.*, B.id AS BookId FROM Books as B " +
                         "INNER JOIN Book_Author AS B2A On B.id = B2A.bookId " +
                         "INNER JOIN Author A On B2A.authorId = A.id;";
        var allAuthorsWithBookId = db.Query<dynamic>(authorsSql).AsList();

        var tagsSql = "SELECT T.*, B.id AS BookId FROM Books as B " +
                      "INNER JOIN Book_Tag AS B2T On B.id = B2T.bookId " +
                      "INNER JOIN Tags T On B2T.tagId = T.id;";
        var allTagsWithBookId = db.Query<dynamic>(tagsSql).AsList();

        var sql = "SELECT * FROM Books as B " +
                  "INNER JOIN Publishers AS P On B.publisherId = P.id;";
        var allBooks = db.Query<Book, Publisher, Book>(sql, (book, publisher) =>
        {
            book.publisher = publisher;
            book.Authors = allAuthorsWithBookId.Where(row => row.BookId == book.id).Select(row => new Author{ id = row.id, name = row.name }).AsList();
            book.Tags = allTagsWithBookId.Where(row => row.BookId == book.id).Select(row => new Tag{ id = row.id, name = row.name }).AsList();
            return book;
        });
        return allBooks;
    }
}
```

You'll need to fix some typos and structural code (like a parenthesis at the end of the `using`) and some missing properties in classes `Author`, `Tag`, etc. but it should be OK after that.